Unable to activate adapty
This is my adapty version.
    "@adapty/react-native-ui": "^2.11.1",
    "react-native-adapty": "^2.11.3"

import { adapty, AdaptyError } from 'react-native-adapty';

adapty.setLogLevel('verbose')
adapty.activate('MY_PUBLIC_KEY');

AdaptyError.onError = err => console.log("error adapty===========", err)

I am getting error when app loads like this.
error adapty=========== [Error: #2002 (notActivated): Request is unsuccessful. https://api.adapty.io/api/v1/sdk/analytics/profiles/f71b5f1a-2ede-422f-9da8-c5c2f62188c0/ Code: 401, Response: {"errors":[{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided.","status":"401","source":{"pointer":"/data"},"code":"not_authenticated"}]}]
I have cofigured the paywall and placements and the state is live now. I have created product as well but I am still getting the error.
I have added Public SDK key from app settings > general but still this issue persist.
